# PHP nl2br, help needed with double additions

Tags: php, nl2br

I have this code

```
       require_once("../Packages/Connection.php");
       $create_object = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Articles` WHERE `group` = 'News' ORDER BY `id` DESC;");

      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($create_object))
        {
        $time = $row[time];
        $date = date("H:i M jS o ",$time);
        print "<form action='Update.php' method='post' float:left;>

                <input hidden='hidden' name='articleId' value='$row[id]'>

                <input hidden='hidden' name='method' value='update'>

                <textarea name='articleText' rows='3' cols='25'>$row[text]</textarea>
                <br />  
                <input type='submit' value=' Update '>
            </form><br />
            <form action='Update.php' method='post'>

                <input hidden='hidden' name='articleId' value='$row[id]'>

                <input hidden='hidden' name='method' value='delete'>

                <input type='submit' value=' Delete ' onClick='return confirmDelete()'float:left;'>

            </form>     
         <hr><br />";
         }
```

And it outputs the text alright, it changes the new line to `<br />` but every time I update, it adds a new, so first time I enter a text like:

```
Hi
My name is Jesper

it outputs Hi <br />
My name is Jesper to the database

and second time if i want to change something, like the name..
Hi <br /><br />
My name is JapSeyz
```

and it continues to add `<br />'s..` how do I limit this to only one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using `nl2br` before storing the text to database. Go and see it there...

The right way is to escape the data (e.g., `nl2br`) only when viewing. The data in the database should be clear, without any modifications regarding escaping for a particular purpose.

In the `<textarea>` element, though, new-lines are already handled without need to insert `<br>` elements in there.

So do not use `nl2br` when storing data and use it only when printing on a page (not in the form element).

Comment: Sorry if i am just being noobish.. but i cannot find the right place to insert the nl2br then :/

Comment: Get it completely out of your code first. Once you notice a page where the text should be broken to lines, but is not, apply it just there. That is, if you display the data entered in the form you posted, let's say using: `<p><?php echo $row['text']; ?></p>`, then just add `nl2br` there: `<p><?php echo nl2br($row['text']); ?></p>` but not when `echo`ing to a `<textarea>`. And to be complete, you should be aware of special characters that might be present in the text you are printing. To make the things safe, use `<p><?php echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row['text'])); ?></p>`

Answer (score 0):

I am fix nl2br bug with my own function:

```
if (!function_exists('snl2br')) {
    function snl2br( $input ) {
        return preg_replace('~(\r?\n\s?)+?~',"<br>",$input);
    }
}
```

i hope it will help you.